# Plotting points on the map from given longitudes and latitudes

Tags: list-manipulation, geography

There is a set of longitudes and latitudes :

```
list = {"(50.775000, 6.083330)", "(56.183330, 10.233330)", "(54.216670,-113.000000)"}
```

I want to plot each point on the map

```
GeoGraphics[GeoMarker[list], GeoBackground -> "Satellite"]
```

but there is an error message.

If I write it by hand it works

```
GeoGraphics[
GeoMarker[{{50.775000, 6.083330}, {56.183330,10.233330}, {54.216670, -113.000000}}], 
GeoBackground -> "Satellite"]
```

[image]

I have a big data of longitudes and latitudes and it is impossible to copy it by hand from `list`.

How to get

```
newlist = {{50.775000, 6.083330}, {56.183330,10.233330}, {54.216670, -113.000000}}
```

from

```
list = {"(50.775000, 6.083330)", "(56.183330,10.233330)", "(54.216670,-113.000000)"}
```

? And can I use `GeoListPlot` instead `GeoGraphics` and `GeoMarker`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to get `newlist` from `list`?

You can process the strings in `list` as follows:

```
newlist = ToExpression@ StringSplit[StringDelete[list, "(" | ")"], ","]

(* {{50.775, 6.08333}, {56.1833, 10.2333}, {54.2167, -113.}} *)
```

which gives

```
GeoGraphics[GeoMarker[newlist], GeoBackground -> "Satellite"]
```

[image]

> Can I use `GeoListPlot` instead of `GeoGraphics` and `GeoMarker`?

A possible way:

```
GeoListPlot[GeoPosition[newlist], GeoBackground -> "Satellite"]
```

[image]